# Components keep disappearing in Altium Library Altium 22.7.1

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, altium

The problem is that when I create components in a schematic library and PCB library I then proceed to save them in that library. From there I can place the components on a schematic with no problem. I take the added steps of compiling the schematic and PCB library files into an integrated library and then also going to Design > Make Integrated Library to try and make sure the components stay there when I go into the project the next time.

Unfortunately, upon entering the project the next time, I find that the components that I had previously made are gone.  At the same time, the said components are still in the schematics, just not in their respective pcb and sch libraries.  My question is, how can I get the components to stop disappearing?

Comment: i.e files are not saving and are virtually reverting back to previous saves where the components and changes were not made

Comment: check permissions wherever the files are saved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround guys. First having multiple sch and pcb libraries with the same file names is not a good idea which was the case in my situation. I did confirm they were in separate directories, but still I believe because they had the same file names, the pointers were probably pointing to other copies of the sch and pcb libraries that weren't edited. What I ended up doing was

1. I changed the name of the source files of the integrated library
2. Then when I was done making my edits, I saved the LibPkg as another name, and then compiled the newly named source files and LibPkg file into an integrated library.
3. The new integrated library kept the changes I had made because the .intlib file and respective source files did not have the same file names as other. Intlib and source files.